# Can I see what is being installed by using Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, installation

I am writing an application for enrollment, and I want to be able to show what is being installed at the moment (not after it is already installed). I had thought I would be able to create a powershell script that would use the variable _SMSTSPackageName and tell me what is currently installing. However, most of the information I've found is just allowing me to see what has already installed. Is it possible to track dynamic installation through a Powershell script? I am very new to powershell, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is being installed"? Installers are not standardized, some programs "install" by doing nothing more than copying a .exe to any folder it wants to (does NOT have to be program files or program files (x86)) and creating a shortcut maybe, where the "installer" is just a .bat file.

Comment: Good question Quantic. I guess this is a difficult task and I'm not sure if I am explaining it correctly. I was wanting to know if there is a way to access the information of what is being installed/copied. Even if it goes by really fast, I would probably just check it every 5 seconds to see if the value changed and then update the label. If some small ones were missed, that's okay. If that makes sense?

Comment: "if there is a way to access the information of what is being installed/copied" -- by what, anything and everything? For an example, download "Process Monitor" from here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx; even with the built in filters that ignore procmon.exe itself and other Windows things I am getting ~10k-100k events per second. You can write your own program to gather some of the same stats (I assume through lots of p/invoke calls), but you need to figure out exactly which .exe's you want to monitor. Note that most installers spawn multiple subprocesses.

Comment: Gotcha. So there isn't really a way to just track the specific packages being pushed through task manager during a computer build?

Comment: What's provoking the question? Another way to ask: What do you really need to know? (Tell _what_ you want to accomplish, not _how_ you think you need to do it.)

Comment: "So there isn't really a way to just track the specific packages being pushed through task manager during a computer build?" -- do you mean "Control Panel" instead of "Task Manager"? And by "computer build" do you mean, "setting up windows, drivers, and programs for the first time after installing it"? There's caveats with 32/64bit, but e.g., most installers will modify the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry key which you could monitor for changes; iirc this is most of the info found in "Control Panel - Programs and Features".

Comment: Oh really Quantic? Yes, I meant setting up windows, drivers, and programs for the first time. Do you know how I would monitor that? Would I write a powershell script to follow a variable?  ---- Good point Bill, I really just need to know if there is a way I can update a label on an application that I am building to give the users some idea of what their computer is installing at that time. Basically, link the label to a variable that changes based on what I'm reading from the terminal/powershell. If possible.